# Unreal Niagara Simulation Stages custom UV Space

Tags: trigonometry, hlsl, unreal-engine5, compute-shader

I am trying to do something with Unreal Niagara simulation stages and kept me blocked for about 3 weeks now. I am using grids and simulation stages.

I have an object moving onto a plane and I want to calculate the UVs along the path so that I can use some functions (sine) to draw vertical/horizontal line along the tangent of the movement direction or apply animation to it.

I have 2 idea, one is to construct the path as a set of line segments and calculate the UVs along each segment, but I have issues calculating the right coordinates where 2 segments merges.
Another idea was to calculate sets of consecutive (quadratic) splines and calculate the UV space as parametrization of 3 consecutive points and distance to it. I am failing with the line segments method while I have not clear how to figure out the coordinate with the spline method.

I'll show my result with the line segments method. Currently working on a set of 2 segments.

[image: Gif]

This is my current result. I plotted the 3 points in blue just to see where they are and I am moving the middle one in a circle. For each point of the plane I calculate the coordinate in the segment space (getting the UV space aligned to the segment) and based on with segments is the closest I write them to the grid.

I think my issue is that there is an area where a point is equally close to the first and second segment, so I thought to find which is the right one to use calculating the sign of the dot product between the normal of the plane bisecting the angle and the vector from P1 to the current processed point.

[image: Example of calculation]

This give me the current result that is not what I would like. Sorry for the bad drawing, but this is the result I would like to have. I do get the right V (red) coordinate if I use the distance to the segments, but I can't figure out at all how to get the U coordinate to interpolate smoothly between the 2 segments (that's why I thought to use a spline interpreting the points as control points, but filing right now)

[image: Expected]